# If $x = y$, $p$ = what?

Tags: radicals, fractions

It is given that,

$$
\frac{\sqrt{2x+3y}+\sqrt{2x-3y}}{\sqrt{2x+3y}-\sqrt{2x-3y}}=p
$$

If $x=y$, $p$ =?

Comment: Have you tried replacing $x$ with $y$ already?

Comment: Yes, but I failed.

Comment: What?! Really?! Why don't you show the working after editing the question?

Comment: do you mean  ?$$
\frac{\sqrt{(2x+3y)}+\sqrt{(2x-3y)}}{\sqrt{(2x+3y)}-\sqrt{(2x-3y)}}=p
$$

Comment: How did you fail? What happened that made you say "you failed"? You haven't given enough detail.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre x can be positive nor negative

Comment: @Ramanujan - Does it really matter?

Comment: If $x=y$, then the numbers under the radicals are $5x$ and $-x$. So some of the radicals will be complex numbers (because you can't have $x=0$ in that case or the form would be $\frac 00$). You will have to define what the radicals mean in that case (choose a branch for the square root).

Comment: As a start, try $x=y=100$ and see what happens. Also try $x=y=-100$

Comment: It seems that the OP has learned that they have no reason to explain **anything** because there'll always be answerers desperate for rep...who oblige even the poorest of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have: $\dfrac{\sqrt{2x+3y}+\sqrt{2x-3y}}{\sqrt{2x+3y}-\sqrt{2x-3y}}=p$

Let's replace $x$ with $y$:

$\Rightarrow p=\dfrac{\sqrt{2y+3y}+\sqrt{2y-3y}}{\sqrt{2y+3y}-\sqrt{2y-3y}}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{\sqrt{5y}+\sqrt{-y}}{\sqrt{5y}-\sqrt{-y}}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{\sqrt{5y}+\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}{\sqrt{5y}-\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}$

Then, let's multiply this fraction by the complex conjugate of its denominator:

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{\sqrt{5y}+\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}{\sqrt{5y}-\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}\cdot{\dfrac{\sqrt{5y}+\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}{\sqrt{5y}+\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{\big(\sqrt{5y}+\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i\big)^{2}}{\big(\sqrt{5y}\big)^{2}-\big(\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i\big)6{2}}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{5y+2\cdot{\sqrt{5y}}\cdot{\sqrt{y}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}+y\cdot{i^{2}}}{5y-y\cdot{i^{2}}}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{5y+2{\sqrt{5y^{2}}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}-y}{5y+y}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{4y+2{\sqrt{5y^{2}}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}}{6y}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{2y+2\sqrt{y^{2}}\sqrt{5}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}{3y}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{2y+2y\sqrt{5}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}{3y}$

$\hspace{9 mm} =\dfrac{2+2\sqrt{5}\hspace{0.5 mm}i}{3}$; $y\neq{0}$

Comment: This is totally correct, but you are actually multiplying the number by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: Thank you for making that clear.

Comment: $\sqrt{-y} = i\sqrt{y}$ whether $y$ is pos, neg, complex or zero, true but in calling $\sqrt{5y} + i \sqrt{y}$ the "complex conjugate" you are implying that you believe $y \ge 0$ which you have utterly no reason to believe.

Answer (score 3):

$
\frac{\sqrt{2x+3y}+\sqrt{2x-3y}}{\sqrt{2x+3y}-\sqrt{2x-3y}}=p
$

Apply componendo and dividendo,

$
\frac{\sqrt{2x+3y}+\sqrt{2x-3y}+\sqrt{2x+3y}-\sqrt{2x-3y}}{\sqrt{2x+3y}+\sqrt{2x-3y}- \sqrt{2x+3y}+\sqrt{2x-3y}}=\frac{p+1}{p-1}
$

$
\frac{\sqrt{2x+3y}}{\sqrt{2x-3y}} = \frac{p+1}{p-1}
$

Put x=y

$
\frac{\sqrt{5y}}{\sqrt{-y}} = \frac{p+1}{p-1}
$

Squaring both sides,

$5.(p-1)^2=-1(p+1)^2$

> Sorry I have little mistake here,
>   $5p^2-10p+5 = -p^2-2p-2$

$5p^2-10p+5 = -p^2-2p-1$

$6p^2-8p+6=0$

$3p^2-4p+3=0$

$D = b^2 - 4ac$

= $(-4)^2 - 4.3.3$ = 16 - 36 = - 20

$ p = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt D}{2a}$

= $\frac{-(-4) \pm \sqrt{-20}}{2.3}$

= $\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{20i^2}}{6}$

= $\frac{4 \pm 2i\sqrt5}{6}$

p = $\frac{2 + i\sqrt5}{3}, \frac{2 - i\sqrt5}{3}$

> Edit-

In above formula D is discriminat. It is used when we can't factorise equation using factorisation method.

[Here's the link when you can't find root using factorisation use discrimat method.](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform2.htm)

Comment: What means $D$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=y$, let's call them both $a$.

Then substituting, we have:

$$
p=\frac{\sqrt{5a}+\sqrt{-a}}{\sqrt{5a}-\sqrt{-a}}
$$

If we multiply the top and bottom by the conjugate, $\sqrt{5a}-\sqrt{-a}$, we get:
$$
p=\frac{5a-(-a)}{5a-2\cdot\sqrt{5a}\cdot\sqrt{-a}+(-a)}
$$$$
p=\frac{6a}{4a-2\cdot\sqrt{-5a^2}}=\frac{6a}{4a-2\cdot a\cdot\sqrt{-5}}
$$$$
p=\frac6{4-2\cdot\sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{-1}}=\frac3{2-\sqrt{5}\cdot i} [if a\neq 0]
$$

This can be further simplified, but from here, a calculator can be used to solve the complex fraction.